# Stored procedure results in CSV format

Tags: t-sql

I have a stored procedure that does a select and returns the results. I would like thos results to be in .csv format. NOT a csv file, a string in csv format. Also, I am not looking for any menu clicks or selections from management studio. This must be done inside the stored procedure call. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: CSV = Comma-Separated Values. So SELECT value1+','+value2+',' + value3 +... FROM MyTable should do the trick

Comment: If you need the column names you can first "SELECT 'col1,col2,col3...' UNION ALL"

Comment: If any columns are bit or int or anything not a string this doesn't work. Also this is a result set of rows. Like I mentioned, I want one single string result with crlf at the end of each row.

Comment: Obviously, any non-char columns should be cast as varchar(n) (where n is the large enough to hold the longest value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you. Column headers is optional:

```
select 'NVarCharColumn1Header,IntColumn2Header' 
            + char(13) + char(10) 
        + (select NVarCharColumn1 
                    + ',' + cast(IntColumn2 as nvarchar) 
                            + char(13) + char(10)
            from Table1
            for xml path(''), type).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

Comment: Still not getting the line breaks in there. Invalid csv format

Comment: how/where do you use the result? the char(13) + char(10) represents CrLf.

Comment: i should be able to take the result string, past it in notepad, save it as a csv and open it in excel. The crlf in this example is not recognized in notepad, notepad++ or excel.

Comment: If you're copying the results from the management studio, it will not work. Try selecting 'results to file' on management studio and save it as CSV. Then try viewing the saved file on notepad++. Even by just 'result to text' you'll see the result has it's own line.

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha. Sweet. Worked, Thank you!